# Is there a special name for a function that changes the cardinality of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a function $f: X \rightarrow X$, a finite set $S\subset X$ and $|S'| \neq |S|$ for  $f(S) = S'$. Is there a special name for such a function $f$?

Comment: Not $1-1.  \ \ \ \ $

Comment: I thought this was going to be about infinite sets!  Does anyone know the name for it in that case?

Comment: Ah, no, $X$ is finite as well

Comment: Yes, that doesn't really matter.  What I thought you were going to be asking for (from the title) is the name for a function $f: X\to X$ where $|f(X)|<|X|$.  If $X$ is infinite, that is a much stronger property than 'not injective'.

Comment: I realised that the comments on another question are a bad place to ask a question, so I've now asked it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318680/name-for-a-function-whose-preimage-has-smaller-cardinality-than-its-domain).

Comment: By the way, I was momentarily confused by the question's usage of "$f(S)$" for the pointwise image of $S$ under $f$.  I think in this context (and most others) it's best to use a different notation like $f[S]$ to avoid confusion with the _value_ of $f$ _at_ $S$.

Comment: @Trevor: I would be confused by $f[S]$, because I'm not sure I've ever seen it before and so I wouldn't be sure if it had some special meaning.  In my experience, $f(S)$ is pretty standard notation for the pointwise image of $S$ under $f$.

Comment: @TaraB I only mentioned it because the question was tagged "elementary-set-theory".  In set theory using $f(S)$ in this way can be ambiguous because the same $S$ can be an _element_ of $\text{dom}(f)$ and also a _subset_ of $\text{dom}(f)$.  The OP hasn't said anything to rule out $S \in X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specifically mention that the image of $S$ under $f$ is smaller than $S$, you could say that $f$ is "not injective on $S$".  Of course $f$ is also not injective at all, as the other answers say, but that is weaker.

Comment: +1, good answer, in fact the formulation of the question appears to require a *name* that refers to both $f$ and $S$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti:  Thanks.  I do think this is probably what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Then you must have $|S'| < |S|$, and you are talking of a function which is not injective.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: in that case it must be that $|S'|<|S|$, and therefore $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Not literally the same answers, but we came close ;-)

Comment: @Andreas: Hard to get much closer!

Comment: So given my edit, 'not injective and not surjective', but that's all

Comment: @Confusion: If $X$ is infinite, your function could be surjective and still have the stated property. E.g., $$f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\;.$$